# Run AMD Rana 455 CPU without retention bracket securing the heat sink?

Tags: cpu, heatsink

I just recently got a 3.3GHz AMD Rana 455 CPU to replace an old X2, but one of the clips on the retention bracket broke off. I have another one ordered, but in the meantime I have some work I need to get at on the drives (and I no longer have a desktop to swap the drive into).

Is it safe to run the computer with the computer on its side and the heat sink just stuck on with the thermal paste for any amount of time?

Thanks in advance!

AMD Athlon II Rana 455 3.3GHz, stock heatsink and fan
MSI 790XT-G45 motherboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## WARNING

**This *could* kill your CPU! Don't do that! Vibration will make the heatsink fall off**

I did quite some hardware hackings, some of what as a proffessional I would not be proud of. But in an emergency, I'd use cable ties to secure the heatsink. In fact, the heatsink in my custom made case is fastened with cable ties too. But in my case (both meanings of the word :) ) there is no place to do anything else, and I check it regularly. Also, the top of the case pushes it against the CPU itself, it can't dislodge or fall off...

**This is something not safe, and not recommended unless this is a HUGE emergency**

Comment: And now I'm very glad I asked.  That factor completely evaded me.  Thanks!